# In Google Sheet : How to split an amount between specific cell value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

My problem is: I order beers. Beers can sometimes comes by 24, 12, 4 or 1. I am trying to find a way to easily divide an amount to specific cell value and have in a cell the remainder if there is one. It will me to order with the best price as possible and also inform me if I have spare items (this is not a problem)

Here is a working proposal but with with very basic formula.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGod88hAa0IeLWHiuzti708Vi4CHmAGKHsZaXuUkiU0/edit#gid=1394645572

How could I improve it? If possible without scripting.

Comment: Maybe with some `=quotient` and `=mod` ?